# Variable is not updating its value inside a file?

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.x

So... I'm currently learning python. I'm trying to create a file which saves the value of a variable (the file is arqLog and the variable is novoArq), but the problem is: the value of the variable updates with +1, but it doesn't happen inside the file. I want the variable to update inside the file so I can add it as a string to the .dat files name and create some kind of backup so the program continue to create .datx files from where it stopped.
(Python 3.4)

```
x = []
y = []
novoArq = 1

cwd = os.getcwd()

def main():
    global novoArq
    global cwd
    resposta = eval(input('\nChose one of the options below:\n\n1. Create data\n2. Plot data\n3. Quit\n\n--> '))
    if resposta == 1:
        try:
            os.mkdir('coordenadas')
            arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','w')
            print('\nA new folder has been created: '+cwd+'/coordenadas')
            arqLog.write(str(novoArq))
            arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','r')
            arqLog2 = arqLog.read()
            x = input('\nType the values for X separated by coma (ex: -10,2.3,5): ')
            y = input('\nType the values for Y separated by coma (ex: -10,2.3,5): ')
            arqx = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/x.dat'+arqLog2,'w')
            arqx.write(x)
            arqx.close()
            arqy = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/y.dat'+arqLog2,'w')
            arqy.write(y)
            arqy.close()
            print("\nThese values were saved: "+cwd+"/coordenadas/x.dat"+arqLog2+" e y.dat"+arqLog2)
            arqLog.close()
            novoArq+=1
            main()
        except:
            arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','r')
            arqLog2 = arqLog.read()
            x = input('\nType the values for X separated by coma (ex: -10,2.3,5): ')
            y = input('\nType the values for Y separated by coma (ex: -10,2.3,5): ')
            arqx = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/x.dat'+arqLog2,'w')
            arqx.write(x)
            arqx.close()
            arqy = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/y.dat'+arqLog2,'w')
            arqy.write(y)
            arqy.close()
            print("\nEsses dados foram arquivados em "+cwd+"/coordenadas/x.dat"+arqLog2+" e y.dat"+arqLog2)
            arqLog.close()
            novoArq+=1
            main()
```

When I print novoArq it outputs an updated value, but when I print arqLog2 it outputs 1 every time.

Comment: What is the `try:`/`except:` for? What exception are you expecting? Are you sure that's the exception you're actually getting?

Comment: Also, you appear to have copied and pasted a long string of code twice. Are you sure the two versions are identical, or is it possible that one of them is correct and the other is wrong?

Comment: I'm using the try and except because of the os.mkdir(). In case the folder already exists it goes to the except block. I'm not sure if it's the better way but seems to be working.

Comment: Then just put the `os.mkdir` inside the `try:`, not a duplicate of all of your code. In other words, `try: os.mkdir(…) except: pass`, and then everything else.

Comment: It's not suppose to pass. In case there already is a folder named 'coordenadas' I want the code to run just like it'd run in case there wasn't a folder named 'coordenadas' there. What changes is the folder creation thing (in except there isn't any folder beeing created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only write `novoArq` if `os.mkdir('coordenadas')` doesn't fail.

It fails after the first time so never writes anything more than `1`.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked. Now I understand how the try/except is suppose to work lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the source of the problem:

```
arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','w')
print('\nA new folder has been created: '+cwd+'/coordenadas')
arqLog.write(str(novoArq))  
arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','r')
```

You are opening the file dat.log for write then before closing it you open it for read,

You should first close the file before opening it again for read:

```
arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','w')
print('\nA new folder has been created: '+cwd+'/coordenadas')
arqLog.write(str(novoArq))  
argLog.close() # **CLOSE THE FILE AFTER WRITE THEN OPEN IT**
arqLog = open(cwd+'/coordenadas/dat.log','r')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense, but doesn't seem to be the problem.